# Where to get installation media for Microsoft Dynamics CRM 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I know this question doesn't really fit stackoverflow but there isnt' much action on the dynamics crm tags.

Where can I find the installation media for Dynamics 365 on premise? It's not on MSDN. The only thing I have been able to find is an update for 2016 to 365.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamics 365 was not published as a new version. It is an update to 2016, "December 2016 Update for Dynamics 365". You should pull down the 2016 ISO to do an install and then apply the update.